# replace single-quote with double-quote, if and only if quote is after specific string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm working in notepad++, and using its find-replace dialog box.
NP++ documentation states: *Notepad++ regular expressions use the Boost regular expression library v1.70, which is based on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) syntax*.  ref: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching

What I'm trying to do *should* be simple, but I'm a regex novice, and after 2-3 hrs of web searches and playing with online regex testers, I give up.
I want to replace all single quotes `'` with double quote `"` , but **if and only if** the `'` is to the RIGHT of one or more `#`, ie inside a python comment.
For example,

```
list1 = ['apple','banana','pear'] # All 'single quotes' to LEFT of # remained unchanged.
list2 = ['tomato','carrot'] # All 'single quotes' to RIGHT of one or more # are replaced 
# # with "double quotes", like this.
```

The np++ file is over 800 lines, manual replacement would be tedious & error prone. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do what you want:

```
(^[^#]*#|(?<!^)\G)[^'\n]*\K'
```

It looks for a `'` which is preceded by either

1. `^[^#]*#` : start of line and some number of non-`#` characters followed by a `#`;  or
2. `(?<!^)\G` : the start of line or the end of the previous match (`\G`), with a negative lookbehind for start of line `(?<!^)`, meaning that it only matches at the end of the previous match

and then some number of non `'` or newline (to prevent the match wrapping around the end of the previous line) characters `[^'\n]*`.

We then use `\K` to reset the match, so that everything before that is discarded from the match, and the regex only matches the `'`.

That can then be replaced with `"`.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NdIz3N/1)

**Update**

You can avoid matching apostrophes within words by only matching ones that are either preceded or followed by a non-word character:

```
(^[^#]*#|(?<!^)\G)[^'\n]*\K('(?=\W)|(?<=\W)')
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NdIz3N/2)

**Update 2**

You can also deal with the case where there are `#` characters in strings by qualifying the first part of the regex with the requirement for there to be matched pairs of quotes beforehand:

```
(?:^[^'#]*(?:'[^']*'[^#']*)*[^'#]*#|(?<!^)\G)[^'\n]*\K(?:'(?=\W)|(?<=\W)')
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NdIz3N/3)

Comment: Minor hiccup if there are words with intentional apostrophe on right side of #, such as the words:  don't , Alice's.   But only a few instances & was more practical to manually fix.

Comment: @TomH I can probably fix the hiccup - it occurs to me there's also another possible hiccup if you have a string which contains `#` to the left of the `#` which marks a comment. Let me think about it and I'll post an update.

Comment: @TomH I've added a fix for both "hiccups"